# Android disable notification bar [root]

Tags: android, root

I need to enable this on 4.2.2 android tablet.
I've successfull'y done that using this terminal command:

```
"settings put global device_provisioned 1"
```

The problem is, that this command also disables HOME button, so I cannot use it. Seems like system stops sending intents.
I've found ways to disable whole system bar at the top and bottom of the screen, but then I loose my navigation buttons.
I've tried disabling notifications one by one, but I still see searching for GPS and Android active hotspot icons in notification bar.

It seems I've tried everything I could, but am unable to get required functionality.
What else could I try?

Comment: Your application use case ? Kiosk Mode ? Can you just make your app full screen?

Comment: You're trying too hard! Like Sean said, just make your app fullscreen.

Comment: App itself is fullscreen, but it also opens few other apps that weren't written by me.